# Test framework to replace Watin, if it would cease being maintained?

Tags: automated-tests, watin, browser-testing

I had the impression that Watin was no longer being maintained and asked to which framework would be the best to switch to for testing of a website in a browser from .net?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Back in July on the WatiN mailing list, Jeroen stated the following.

> ...is WatiN still alive: Yes. Is the activity visible for the outside
>   world: No, which is a bad thing.
>
> During my holiday last two weeks I have been thinking about how to
>   proceed and decided that I will work on WatiN every Thursday evening.
>   Number one prio is get the updated FireFox support and IE improvements
>   out asap.

.

If moving away from WatiN, then Selenium 2 or later would be my first choice for a framework.  Coded UI would be next.  I've been part of a testing exercise where in the room WatiN, Selenium and Coded UI were all used to test the same site; the resulting structure was oddly similar across all three.  Selenium seemed to have the best support for multiple browsers.