# Is WatiN discontinued?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, download, automated-tests, watin

I was searching for help with an issue involving IE 9 and WatiN when I noticed that almost all questions & answers were made in 2011. At that time, most of the people answering said that an update would be released soon to resolve the issues. However we are in 2013 and the last update is dated from April 2011.

[WatiN 2.1 (released on 12 April 2011)](http://watin.org/documentation/)

Does anyone know if the WatiN project was discontinued?

Is there a good alternative to WatiN?

Comment: See my answer here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399483/test-framework-to-replace-watin-if-it-would-cease-being-maintained/13405840#13405840

Comment: [This answer][1] sums it up really well.


  [1]: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4107/what-is-a-preferred-ui-testing-framework-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be pretty dead by now, even their website is down. That's a pitty. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For .NET why not going with test support from VisualStudio2012 ? You get [coded UI test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx) and all that jazz. It even supposed to be [cross browser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/30/introducing-cross-browser-testing-with-coded-ui-tests.aspx). Note that you might need VS [Premium or Ultimate](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare#feature-chart-heading).

If VS is not available for you try selenium/webdriver

- selenium docs [Selenium WebDriver with .Net bindings](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#c)
- also you might want to check out [selenium toolkit](http://seleniumtoolkit.codeplex.com/)
- otherwise [few related SO questions might help](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=selenium%20%5B.net%5D)
- worst case scenario just [google this](https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium%20.net)

Comment: I switched over to Selenium myself about a year ago from WatiN and was very refreshed. Though this was originally due to multi-browser support and all other reasons are my opinion.

Comment: The Coded Ui Test from Visual Studio works only by accessing hardware device calls directly, things like Mouse.Click(uIActionsPane2, new Point(15, 11) and i dont think that this is an elegant solution. Watin seems much more accurate for tests since it uses the browser directly. Using Watin i can even perform another task while running tests in my computer. 
I guess that i'll try the Selenium.

Comment: Just spent the last 3 days trying to try Selenium. Jesus it's a mess.